# how to hide multiple markers when zooming out

Tags: javascript

Any one know how to avoid a same marker  shown in multiple time

```
      latlngbounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
      map.setCenter(latlngbounds);
      map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this feature bu using Google Map Marker Cluster.

Greate tutorial is here.

https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html